# play the sound again when the user get back to activity

Tags: android, media-player, audio

what i have is an activity which i play some sound each the user open it , but when he got to the child activity of it .. it stops as i want .. but i want the user when he press back button and return to this activity (which is parent activity) to play this sound again ... how can i do this .. here is some of my code:

```
 public class GeneralScreen extends Activity {
    String mytext="";
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    protected static final int RESULT_SPEECH = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.general_screen);


        GridView g = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.myGrid);
         mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.selecteng);
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
        mMediaPlayer.start();

        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                Log.i("Completion Listener","Song Complete");
                Toast.makeText(GeneralScreen.this, "Media Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);  //for open google API
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");     //for transfer voice from google API to text in EditText

                try {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);  // for get result


                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
                    Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),   //if make error get this message
                            "Ops! Your device doesn't support Speech to Text",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    t.show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a method playYourMusic() and put all the code to start mediaplayer inside. Then put the playYourMusic into onRestart and in onCreate():

```
    @Override
   protected void onRestart() {

    playYourMusic();

     super.onRestart();


   }
```

Think on it, to finish the activity that You are leaving when You will go back to main. So, why not in onResume()? Because onResume() is also called at the start of Activity. Some devices handle the LifeCycle of android in a different way.

Comment: Pls explain a bit more about "Some devices handle the LifeCycle of android in a different way."

Comment: It is a experience that I made with Samsung Galaxy S3 and Samsung Note 10.1 . I installed and started an app in the same Stadium, on Note 10.1 onResume() was not called as often as on Galaxy S3.

Comment: interesting. Will add it to my list of exceptions to the rule. thx

Answer (score 0):

You just use following methods `@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        //play music code here
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
      //stop music code here
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute your playSound() method in the appropriate lifecycle method (in this case I think it would likely be `onResume()` ).

Understanding the Activity lifecycle is very fundamental, and important to understand, please check the following resource for more information:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html